# Basic URL opener in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, url

I'm trying to create a simple ruby script that opens a bunch of URLs in Bing by looping through simple searches of the numbers 1-40, but when I run this in terminal I get:

"undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

num = 0
target = 40

while start < target do
   open("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + $num)
   num += 1
end
```

(Sorry if it's some simple mistake, this is my first ruby program.)

Update: **
Ok, thanks for catching that!

now it's giving me this error:

`+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)

how do I incorporate the two? Is there some type of parser like in Java?

---

Thank you Arup and Mischa!

Comment: `$start` is not defined.

Comment: You shouldn't use the dollar sign in Ruby (unless you want to define a global variable, which is not the case here)

Comment: I fixed it also *`+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)*. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as below to fix your code :

```
while $num < $target do
   open("http://www.bing.com/search?q=#{$num}")
   $num += 1
end
```

You didn't  define any where the variable `$start`. I think you should use there `$num`. I would recommend to use only local variable for this purposes, like `num`,`target`. Don't need global variables.

`open("http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + $num)` also wouldn't work. As you are trying to *concat* a *number* with a *string*. Either convert the number to a string using `#to_s` or use *string interpolation*, as I did below.

Without global variable write as :

```
while num < target do
   open("http://www.bing.com/search?q=#{num}") # better
   # or write as open( "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + num.to_s )
   num += 1
end
```

Comment: If you recommend using local variables, the code in your answer should reflect that.